# Bulk rename files from csv files r

Tags: r, file, bulk, renaming

I am struggling to find a clear answer to by problem.

I have a dataframe that has a file path and a filename.

`data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables: $ Path : Factor w/ 97 levels "J:\\GBD2017\\China\\Splitweekly\\281_2010_10.pdf",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 $ Filename: Factor w/ 97 levels "1000095452.pdf",..: 97 1 2 3 4 5`

I want to rename each filepath `J:\\GBD2017\\China\\Splitweekly\\281_2010_10.pdf` so the last xx_xx_xx.pdf is replaced with the value in the filename column.

eg `J:\\GBD2017\\China\\Splitweekly\\281_2010_10.pdf` would become  `J:\\GBD2017\\China\\Splitweekly\\1000095452.pdf`.

I am going to have hundreds of files so any method needs to be efficient.

Dput:

```
structure(list(Path = structure(1:6, .Label = c("J:\\GBD2017\\China    \\Splitweekly\\281_2010_10.pdf", 
`"J:\\GBD2017\\China\\Splitweekly\\282_2010_11.pdf", "J:\\GBD2017\\China    \\Splitweekly\\283_2010_12.pdf"), class = "factor"), Filename = `structure(c(97L, 1L, 2L, 3L, L, 5L), .Label = c("1000095452.pdf","1000095453.pdf", "1000095454.pdf"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Path", "Filename"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `?dirname` ; `?basename` ; `?file.path`

Comment: Im not sure what you are saying

Comment: I'm suggesting you read the documentation for those three functions as they're all you'll need to accomplish your goal.